# How do I load windows 7 on my netbook from a USB key? Failing on CD/DVD Driver

Tags: windows-7, windows, netbook

I'm trying to load windows 7 on my brand new Acer   Aspire One netbook.  I made my USB key bootable etc. and windows begins to load from it.  During the first stage of the install, it stops and says it can't find a required CD/DVD driver, there isn't one on the machine.  The bios shows an IDE CD, but i can't *disable* it. I'm not sure what driver it's looking for or why, but i can't get past it.

Acer  Aspire One netbook,  2gb ram, 250gb drive.
Current OS:  Vista
Installing: Windows 7

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your image of Windows correctly downloaded and transferred onto the USB key? I actually ran into an issue where Windows wouldn't install - turned out the downloaded image I had was no good. I would start there and try again.

Comment: Turns out it was the image - install worked fine on a different copy. If you post this response as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at several guides describing the process and none make any reference to changing the installation files (to redirect it to a USB stick) or changing any settings (except booting from USB).

Therefore I'd go with ifferte's suggestion and either download it again unless you are sure the image worked on another pc. In that case I would reformat the USB stick and try the copying of the files again.

Check [this guide from MaximumPC](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/how_to_install_windows_7_beta_a_usb_key) just to be sure

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you made your USB install, but try [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/).  I used it with great results installing windows 7 to my netbook.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried extracting the contents of the iso to the flash drive?